# PyTorch does not make initial weights random

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, windows-10

I created a Neural Network that takes two greyscale images 14x14 pixels portraying a digit (from MNIST database) and returns 1 if the first digit is less or equal to the second digit, returns 0 otherwise. **The code runs, but every time the initial weights are the same. They should be random**
Forcing the initial weights to be random, by using the following line of code in the Net class, does not help.

```
torch.nn.init.normal_(self.layer1.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.01)
```

Here is the code of the "main.py" file:

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "TRUE"
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from dlc_practical_prologue import *


class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(2*14*14, 32)
        #torch.nn.init.normal_(self.layer1.weight, mean=0.0, std=0.01)
        #self.layer2 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        #self.layer3 = nn.Linear(100, 100)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(32, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.layer1(x))
        #x = torch.relu(self.layer2(x))
        #x = torch.relu(self.layer3(x))
        x = torch.sigmoid(self.layer2(x))
        return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Data initialization
    N = 1000
    train_input, train_target, train_classes, _, _, _, = generate_pair_sets(N)
    _, _, _, test_input, test_target, test_classes = generate_pair_sets(N)

    train_input = train_input.view(-1, 2*14*14)
    test_input = test_input.view(-1, 2*14*14)

    train_target = train_target.view(-1, 1)
    test_target = test_target.view(-1, 1)

    # I convert the type to torch.float32
    train_input, train_target, train_classes, test_input, test_target, test_classes = \
        train_input.type(torch.float32), train_target.type(torch.float32), train_classes.type(torch.long), \
        test_input.type(torch.float32), test_target.type(torch.float32), test_classes.type(torch.long)


    # Create the neural network
    net = Net()


    # Training
    learning_rate = 0.01
    # Use MSELoss
    loss = nn.MSELoss()
    # Use Adam optimizer
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

    EPOCHS = 50

    for param in net.parameters():
        print(param)

    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
        target_predicted = net(train_input)
        l = loss(train_target, target_predicted)  #loss = nn.MSELoss()
        #l = loss(target_predicted, train_target)
        l.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        #print(l)


    # Testing
    total = 1000
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        correct = ( test_target == net(test_input).round() ).sum()

    print("Accuracy %.2f%%" % (correct / total * 100))
```

Here is the code for "dlc_practical_monologue.py":

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
import torch
from torchvision import datasets

import argparse
import os

import urllib

######################################################################

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='DLC prologue file for practical sessions.')

parser.add_argument('--full',
                    action='store_true', default=False,
                    help = 'Use the full set, can take ages (default False)')

parser.add_argument('--tiny',
                    action='store_true', default=False,
                    help = 'Use a very small set for quick checks (default False)')

parser.add_argument('--seed',
                    type = int, default = 0,
                    help = 'Random seed (default 0, < 0 is no seeding)')

parser.add_argument('--cifar',
                    action='store_true', default=False,
                    help = 'Use the CIFAR data-set and not MNIST (default False)')

parser.add_argument('--data_dir',
                    type = str, default = None,
                    help = 'Where are the PyTorch data located (default $PYTORCH_DATA_DIR or \'./data\')')

# Timur's fix
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                    help = 'quick hack for jupyter')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.seed >= 0:
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)

######################################################################
# The data

def convert_to_one_hot_labels(input, target):
    tmp = input.new_zeros(target.size(0), target.max() + 1)
    tmp.scatter_(1, target.view(-1, 1), 1.0)
    return tmp

def load_data(cifar = None, one_hot_labels = False, normalize = False, flatten = True):

    if args.data_dir is not None:
        data_dir = args.data_dir
    else:
        data_dir = os.environ.get('PYTORCH_DATA_DIR')
        if data_dir is None:
            data_dir = './data'

    if args.cifar or (cifar is not None and cifar):
        print('* Using CIFAR')
        cifar_train_set = datasets.CIFAR10(data_dir + '/cifar10/', train = True, download = True)
        cifar_test_set = datasets.CIFAR10(data_dir + '/cifar10/', train = False, download = True)

        train_input = torch.from_numpy(cifar_train_set.data)
        train_input = train_input.transpose(3, 1).transpose(2, 3).float()
        train_target = torch.tensor(cifar_train_set.targets, dtype = torch.int64)

        test_input = torch.from_numpy(cifar_test_set.data).float()
        test_input = test_input.transpose(3, 1).transpose(2, 3).float()
        test_target = torch.tensor(cifar_test_set.targets, dtype = torch.int64)

    else:
        print('* Using MNIST')

        ######################################################################
        # import torchvision

        # raw_folder = data_dir + '/mnist/raw/'
        # resources = [
            # ("https://fleuret.org/dlc/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "f68b3c2dcbeaaa9fbdd348bbdeb94873"),
            # ("https://fleuret.org/dlc/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "d53e105ee54ea40749a09fcbcd1e9432"),
            # ("https://fleuret.org/dlc/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz", "9fb629c4189551a2d022fa330f9573f3"),
            # ("https://fleuret.org/dlc/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz", "ec29112dd5afa0611ce80d1b7f02629c")
        # ]

        # os.makedirs(raw_folder, exist_ok=True)

        # # download files
        # for url, md5 in resources:
            # filename = url.rpartition('/')[2]
            # torchvision.datasets.utils.download_and_extract_archive(url, download_root=raw_folder, filename=filename, md5=md5)
        ######################################################################

        mnist_train_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = True, download = True)
        mnist_test_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = False, download = True)

        train_input = mnist_train_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
        train_target = mnist_train_set.targets
        test_input = mnist_test_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
        test_target = mnist_test_set.targets

    if flatten:
        train_input = train_input.clone().reshape(train_input.size(0), -1)
        test_input = test_input.clone().reshape(test_input.size(0), -1)

    if args.full:
        if args.tiny:
            raise ValueError('Cannot have both --full and --tiny')
    else:
        if args.tiny:
            print('** Reduce the data-set to the tiny setup')
            train_input = train_input.narrow(0, 0, 500)
            train_target = train_target.narrow(0, 0, 500)
            test_input = test_input.narrow(0, 0, 100)
            test_target = test_target.narrow(0, 0, 100)
        else:
            print('** Reduce the data-set (use --full for the full thing)')
            train_input = train_input.narrow(0, 0, 1000)
            train_target = train_target.narrow(0, 0, 1000)
            test_input = test_input.narrow(0, 0, 1000)
            test_target = test_target.narrow(0, 0, 1000)

    print('** Use {:d} train and {:d} test samples'.format(train_input.size(0), test_input.size(0)))

    if one_hot_labels:
        train_target = convert_to_one_hot_labels(train_input, train_target)
        test_target = convert_to_one_hot_labels(test_input, test_target)

    if normalize:
        mu, std = train_input.mean(), train_input.std()
        train_input.sub_(mu).div_(std)
        test_input.sub_(mu).div_(std)

    return train_input, train_target, test_input, test_target

######################################################################

def mnist_to_pairs(nb, input, target):
    input = torch.functional.F.avg_pool2d(input, kernel_size = 2)
    a = torch.randperm(input.size(0))
    a = a[:2 * nb].view(nb, 2)
    input = torch.cat((input[a[:, 0]], input[a[:, 1]]), 1)
    classes = target[a]
    target = (classes[:, 0] <= classes[:, 1]).long()
    return input, target, classes

######################################################################

def generate_pair_sets(nb):
    if args.data_dir is not None:
        data_dir = args.data_dir
    else:
        data_dir = os.environ.get('PYTORCH_DATA_DIR')
        if data_dir is None:
            data_dir = './data'

    train_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = True, download = True)
    train_input = train_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
    train_target = train_set.targets

    test_set = datasets.MNIST(data_dir + '/mnist/', train = False, download = True)
    test_input = test_set.data.view(-1, 1, 28, 28).float()
    test_target = test_set.targets

    return mnist_to_pairs(nb, train_input, train_target) + \
           mnist_to_pairs(nb, test_input, test_target)

######################################################################
```

Note that I have to add the following line of code to run the code on Windows 10, while it is not necessary to run it on Linux.

```
import os; os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "TRUE"
```

Also on Linux I always get the same initial weights.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. With or without the `nn.init` line, I get different initial weights each time a new `Net()` is instantiated.

Comment: When I run on Windows 10 I get always the same initial weights. Also on Linux I always get the same weights. But I just realized that on Linux the initial weights are different from Windows 10.

Comment: If I write print(torch.rand(1)) before the Net class I always get the same value printed, which means that the random seed is always the same. Weird

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong here but only the weights of the first layer should be the same each time you run this. The thing is when you import the `dlc_practical_monologue.py` there's this thing in it:

```
if args.seed >= 0:
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
```

which fires up if the seed is >=0 (default is 0).
This should only initialize the first layer with the same weights for each run. Check if this is the case.

Comment: Unfortunately, the weights of every layer are the same every time I run the program. I solved by adding torch.manual_seed(time.time()) at the beginning of the main but in the assignment I have to complete I am not allowed to use the library "time"

Comment: So even if you remove this 
```
if args.seed >= 0:
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
```
from dlc_practical_monologue.py and if you don't include any seed manipulation, the weights are still the same for every run? Interesting

Comment: I removed ``` if args.seed >= 0: torch.manual_seed(args.seed) ``` and now it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to delete the following lines from "dlv_practical_prologue.py":

```
if args.seed >= 0:
    torch.manual_seed(args.seed)
```